# Как убрать автозаполнение input?

Tags: html, css

Еще один вопрос, работаю с input и постоянно предлагает выбрать предыдущие данные, как это убрать?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Или на всю форму

```
<form action="/action.php" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
<input type="text" name="text" autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')" >
```

На текущий момент, лично для меня, этот вариант оказался наиболее универсальным. Так как во многих браузерах параметр `autocomplete="off"` сейчас игнорируется и так или иначе, начинает срабатывать автозаполнение.